# OpenMP sections and flush

Tags: c++, openmp

Using the flush command in my openMP sections, I am able to avoid the Access violation error. The functions used in the sections shared several identical arguments. Here is the pseudo-code :

```
int flag = 0;

#pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(2)
{
  #pragma omp section
  {
     function1(...);
     #pragma omp flush
     flag = 1;
     #pragma omp flush(flag)
  }

  #pragma omp section 
  {
     #pragma omp flush(flag)
     while (!flag) {
        #pragma omp flush(flag)
     }
     #pragma omp flush
     function2(...);
  }
}
```

It works well but when I try to add one more section, I have an Access violation error during my program run. Basically I add my third sections like the second one and I set the num_threads to 3.

```
int flag = 0;

#pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(3)
{
  #pragma omp section
  {
     function1(...);
     #pragma omp flush
     flag = 1;
     #pragma omp flush(flag)
  }

  #pragma omp section 
  {
     #pragma omp flush(flag)
     while (!flag) {
        #pragma omp flush(flag)
     }
     #pragma omp flush
     function2(...);
  }

  #pragma omp section 
  {
     #pragma omp flush(flag)
     while (!flag) {
        #pragma omp flush(flag)
     }
     #pragma omp flush
     function3(...);
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong with the above program ?

Comment: "Am I doing something wrong with the above program ?" Umm, going parallel and then jumping through hoops in a horrible way to serialize execution! The whole thing seems pointless...

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution of my problem. Here is the correct code.

```
int flag = 0;

#pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(3)
{
   #pragma omp section
   {
     function1(...);
     #pragma omp flush
     flag++;
     #pragma omp flush(flag)
   }

   #pragma omp section 
   {
       #pragma omp flush(flag)
       while (flag != 1) {
          #pragma omp flush(flag)
       }
       #pragma omp flush
       function2(...);
   }

   #pragma omp section 
   {
       #pragma omp flush(flag)
       while (flag != 2) {
          #pragma omp flush(flag)
       }
       #pragma omp flush
       function3(...);
   }
}
```